# How do I force Craft to regenerate assets transform?

Tags: assets, image-transforms

I had to add an image size in the assets transforms; all my pics were previously uploaded, but when I use `getUrl('headIpad')`, it makes urls like this:

`http://host.com/cpresources/transforms/4/`

Instead of this:

`http://host.com/uploads/team-photo/_headIpad/fall-back.jpg`

I tried to use generateTransformsBeforePageLoad in my config but Craft generates an error:

> Internal Server Error
>   Image “fall-back.jpg” cannot be found.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should probably mark the question as answered if the solution under worked for you. It worked for me, at least.

Answer (score 17):

If you simply go into your `craft_assettransformindex` table and **empty it**, that should trigger brand new transformations for everything.

Answer (score 2):

Let me add, for those like me who just moved to a different server, before you dump the table, make sure your assets directory is writable by Craft. I did what Lindsey D suggested, and it recreated the table nicely (with no errors noted) but didn't actually create the images, because I didn't have the directory writable.