# Updated Image Transformation

Tags: image-transforms, image

Aside from Defining Transforms in the template (http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/image-transforms) is there a way to go back and trigger an image transformation?

We've got a number of assets that have been uploaded to rackspace that need image an image transformation but the transformation was created after the images were uploaded.

Is there a way to kick this off?

Comment: Looks to be a dupe? https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/117/is-there-a-way-to-force-assets-to-redo-transforms and https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/742/how-do-i-force-craft-to-regenerate-assets-transform

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I forgot we added a tool for this, too, under Settings->Tools->Clear Caches Tool->Asset Transform Index.

Answer (score 0):

Probably administration panel -> settings -> tools -> Update Asset Indexes

Comment: The Update Asset Indexes feature makes Craft re-index your asset sources, for example if an asset had been uploaded to the site outside of Craft (FTP etc), running this would get the file(s) showing in Craft. I believe that running this will not trigger the image transformation process for images that have already been indexed.